# Can I remove bold text from zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh (and also oh-my-zsh), but something I wanted to change is the bold text. I would like to completely remove any bold text (make it regular weight) in my terminal. Is it possible? [image: my terminal]
I want the pink colored text to be with regular weight (not bold) like the blue and white text.

I'm using Hyper as my terminal

Comment: You configure this in your terminal conf, not your shell.

Comment: Do you want zsh to never show anything in bold, but other terminal applications should be able to use bold? Or do you want all terminal applications to show bold text as regular weight but a brighter color? Or do you want all terminal applications to show bold text like regular text?

Comment: It can be any of these solutions. I'm using hyper as my terminal, so if its only disabled in hyper it is fine. However it would be nice if I could disable it for all terminal apps or zsh.

Answer (score 1):

For HyperTerminal you add `fontWeightBold: 'normal'` to your config.

Comment: Doesn't work for me!

Comment: @LucasBernardi can you paste your config